# MVVMCross Dynamic Fragments

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I've been exploring MVVMCross for android recently and I came across Dynamic Fragments and I'm a bit confused on the usage. I'm fairly new to the topic so I apologize in advance.

I wanted to test out using fragments with a quiz app example. A question is shown with a back and previous button at the bottom of the page to navigate between questions. Below the question will display a answer selection which is a response type that must change dynamically based on the question type.

So for example the first question may ask "Would you agree that Summer is the best season of the year?" and have the response type as a radio group (i.e. agree, neutral, disagree) and the next question may ask "What is your name?" have a response type of free response (i.e. edit textbox).

Would using `FrameLayouts` be my best bet? How do I update the response type section of the view by using `FrameLayouts` and referencing a `ResponseType ViewModel`?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Would using FrameLayouts be my best bet?

I think there are lots of ways this could be implemented - using fragments, using MvxFrameControl, using custom controls or even using a databound ListView or LinearLayout (taking advantage of its template selection).

The only way to find out which is 'best' is to have a go.

> How do I update the response type section of the view by using FrameLayouts and referencing a ResponseType ViewModel?

You could do this using some kind of ViewModel type to View type lookup - e.g. like in http://enginecore.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/more-dynamic-android-fragments-with.html

Or you could do i using some code behind like in a polymorphic list adapter - e.g. https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Working%20With%20Collections/Collections.Droid/Views/PolymorphicListItemTypesView.cs

For a small set of answer types, don't feel you have to engineer very much - a small `switch` statement or a small lookup `Dictionary` should probably work.

Main advice is to prototype a couple of ways - experiment to see what works for your app.

Comment: Thank you @Stuart! I will try your recommendations!